# MySql: count number of times a word is in a cell and put the number beside the word in bra

Tags: mysql, count

I need the table to have:

accountprefix needs to have 'Oil" (####) for the count of how many times 'Oil' is in that cell

```
SELECT
  jurisdiction,
  Replace(REPLACE(REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT LEFT(fileno, 1)ORDER BY fileno DESC SEPARATOR ', '),'O','Oil')'M','Mobile'),'R','Real')AS accountprefix
From
  table.tester
WHERE
  statuscode = 'A'
  AND builddateid = '2023'
GROUP BY jurisdiction;
```

accountprefix needs to have 'Oil" (####) for the count of how many times 'Oil' is in that cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following where I modified the query to count and display the number of times 'Oil' appears in the `accountprefix` by replacing 'O' with 'Oil (count)' where the count represents the occurrences of 'O' in the `fileno` column for each `jurisdiction`.

```
SELECT
  jurisdiction,
  REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
      REPLACE(
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT LEFT(fileno, 1) ORDER BY fileno DESC SEPARATOR ', '),
        'O', CONCAT('Oil (', COUNT(CASE WHEN LEFT(fileno, 1) = 'O' THEN 1 END), ')')
      ),
      'M', 'Mobile'
    ),
    'R', 'Real'
  ) AS accountprefix
FROM
  table.tester
WHERE
  statuscode = 'A'
  AND builddateid = '2023'
GROUP BY jurisdiction;
```

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I needed.  My head was swimming